# Google Pinyin Input (IME) keeps asking for Google account permission

Tags: google, permissions, lineageos, 7.1-nougat

[Google Pinyin Input](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.pinyin) is an input method (IME) for Chinese.

It keeps asking me for Google account permission.

I deny it all the time, but it always comes back and asks again when I reboot (which is quite often). The IME works perfectly without that permission.

**Question: How to deny the permission once for all?**

- I have a Nexus 5 with Android 7.1.2 / LineageOS 14.1-20170718.
- It always pops up one request for each of the Google accounts I have configured in the Gmail app. I never use pinyin in Gmail.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 14):

I had this problem. I'd half installed Pinyin so continual prompting for a login account.
Go to Google play store and search for Google Pinyin Input. When that appeared there was an option to uninstall it (because it had already been installed).

Comment: So, what is the procedure to solve the problem? Uninstall and then install again? (I still want to use it) Thanks!

Comment: Uninstalling helped. I don't know how it had been installed to my device (I only installed Turkish lately), but I don't need it so removing was the best option. @NicolasRaoul I guess the app requires that access for something (probably to propose personalized word suggestions - I dunno) - so likely there's no way to just disable the permissions request forever.

Comment: I don't see why you would need it installed unless you can read Chinese.

Comment: Thanks!  This happened to me too.  It is very confusing to continually get these permission requests.  I did not install it and it has been a problem since getting the phone.